# javascript send one way message to php

Tags: php, javascript

How can I use javascript to send a one way message to php?  I would like to get the browser information from javascript and just send it to php in the background.  I know I can get some of this from php, but I'd rather use javascript.  Is there a way to do this without a framework like jquery?

Comment: Yes it is a way to do this without a framework, but you'll need to make an XMLHTTPRequest crafted by hand to get it working cross browser. Further info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with something like this:

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
       // IE
       self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            alert('Here goes something');
            self.xmlHttpReq.send('browser info here');
        }
    }
}
```

This will send "browser info here" as POST in the php page you pass to the function as url. I didnt test it though

Comment: you shouldn't use `"Microsoft.XMLHTTP"` - see eg http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx ; I suggest writing a small wrapper like http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/xmlhttprequest.js so you can use `new XMLHttpRequest()` cross-browser; also, your use of `self` is dodgy as `this` will be `window` if `xmlhttpPost` is called without `new`

Comment: I dont like to put code here that will solve all problems, rather point people in the right direction. I wrote this code from memory and I used it once, long ago in one of my first projects and it did work that time.. I never said that its water proof, since I wrote it completely from memory. I would favor jQuery over this approach any time though.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to submit an AJAX request to a PHP script. Yes, you could do it without using a framework but I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an AJAX call to a PHP page, preferably using POST. Any data you want to send needs to be sent along with the request.

I recommend using a framework such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), but if you insist on using raw JavaScript, you want to research [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 0):

```
// fix for older IE versions
// see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx
if( typeof window.XMLHttpRequest === 'undefined' &&
    typeof window.ActiveXObject === 'function') {
    window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0'); } catch(e) {}
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0'); } catch(e) {}
        return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    };
}

function postData(url, data, errhandler) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status !== 200 && errhandler)
            errhandler(this);
    };
    try {
        req.open('POST', url, true); // async post request
        req.send(data);
    }
    catch(e) {
        if(errhandler)
            errhandler(req);
    }
}
```